# Distribution of harmonic sums mod 1

Tags: nt.number-theory, real-analysis

This is only to satisfy my curiosity.  Consider  the harmonic sums

$$ H_n =1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots +\frac{1}{n},\;\;n=1,2,\dotsc, $$

and denote by $h_n$ their mod $1$ reductions,

$$   h_n=H_n\bmod 1=H_n-\lfloor H_n\rfloor\in [0,1),\;\;\forall n. $$

It is not very hard  to see that this sequence $(h_n)_{n\geq 1}$  is dense in $[0,1]$, i.e., for any $x\in [0,1]$ there is a subsequence of $(h_n)$ converging to $x$.

Is  the sequence $(h_n)_{n\geq 1}$ equidistributed?   Better yet,  consider the probability measures

$$ 
\mu_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \delta_{h_k},
$$
where $\delta_r$ denotes the Dirac measure concentrated at $r$.   The sequence $(\mu_n)$ is precompact in the topology of weak convergence of probability measures. Does is converges weakly to some  probability measure on $[0,1]$? If yes, what is the limit?

Comment: The sequence grows too slowly to be  equidistributed.  Compare with the behavior mod 1 of log(n)+C.

Comment: Concerning the non-equidistribution of log n, see page 8 of the book of Kuipers-Niederreiter.

Comment: Here's an observation that confuses me. One proof of the divergence of the harmonic series is by comparison with the series $$1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^{2^n}2^{-n}\right)$$ and it looks like the partial sums of the latter are uniformly distributed $\bmod 1$

Comment: @LiviuNicolaescu: At best, the uniform distribution can be one limit point among many. If $\mu_N\simeq dx$ for some large $N$, then you need $\gtrsim N$ more steps to get away from the current value $h_N$, so $\mu_{(1+c)N}$ will be close to a different measure.